# Github Actions behave different comparing to a local environment

Tags: python, bash, git, github, continuous-integration

I have created a GitHub actions pipeline to do linting of the recent committed code. The test script works in my local environment, but not on the GitHub server. What peculiarity I don't notice?

Here is my code for linting:

```bash
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    
    LATEST_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD);
    echo "Analyzing code changes under the commit hash: $LATEST_COMMIT";
    FILES_UNDER_THE_LATEST_COMMIT=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $LATEST_COMMIT);
    echo "Files under the commit:";
    echo $FILES_UNDER_THE_LATEST_COMMIT;
    MATCHES=$(echo $FILES_UNDER_THE_LATEST_COMMIT | grep '.py');
    echo "Files under the commit with Python extension: $MATCHES";
    echo "Starting linting...";
    if echo $MATCHES | grep -q '.py';
    then
      echo $MATCHES | xargs pylint --rcfile .pylintrc;
    else
      echo "Nothing to lint";
    fi
```

Here is my GitHub Actions config:

```yaml
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.10"]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'NO_LINT')"
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pylint psycopg2 snowflake-connector-python pymssql
        chmod +x .github/workflows/run_linting.sh
    - name: Analysing all Python scripts in the project with Pylint
      if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'CHECK_ALL')"
      run: pylint --rcfile .pylintrc lib processes tests
    - name: Analysing the latest committed changes Pylint
      if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'NO_LINT')"
      run: .github/workflows/run_linting.sh
```

What I get in GitHub:
[image: What I get in GitHub]

And what on my computer:
[image: And what on my computer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem in a nutshell:

> ```yaml
>     steps:
>     - uses: actions/checkout@v3
> ```

By default, `checkout@v2` and `checkout@v3` make a *shallow* (depth 1), single-branch clone.  Such a clone has exactly one commit in it: the most recent one.

As a consequence, this:

> ```bash
> git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $LATEST_COMMIT
> ```

produces no output at all.  There's no parent commit available to compare against.  (I'd argue that this is a bit of a bug in Git: `git diff-tree` should notice that the parent is *missing* due to the `.git/shallow` grafts file.  However, `git diff-tree` traditionally produces an empty diff for a root commit, and without special handling *in* `git diff-tree`, the shallow clone makes `git diff-tree` *think* this is a root commit.  Oddly, the user-oriented `git diff` would treat every file as added—still not what you want, but it would have actually *worked*.)

To fix this, force the depth to be at least 2.  Using `depth: 0` will force a full (non-shallow) clone, but the reason for using a shallow, single-branch clone is to speed up the action by omitting unnecessary commits.  As only the first two "layers" of commit are required here, `depth: 2` provides the correct number.

Side note: your `bash` code has every command terminated with a semicolon.  This works fine, but is unnecessary (it reminds me of doing too much C or C++ programming.<sup>1</sup>  Also, you can just run `git diff-tree <options> HEAD`: there's no need for a separate `git rev-parse` step here (though you might still want that in the `echo`).

---

<sup>1</sup>As I switch from C to C++ to Go to Python to shell etc., I either put in too many or too few parentheses and semicolons, leading to C compiler errors from:

```c
if x == 0 {
```

because my brain is in Go mode.  When I switch back to hacking on the Go code, I put in too many parentheses, but `gofmt` removes them and there's no compile error.

Comment: you're the gott of GitHub Actions! Thanks! That detail of them was really absolutely not obvious!

Comment: @BogdanLashkov: actually I'm not particular good at GitHub Actions (which have lots of their own complexity). I just recognize this particular problem because I've hit shallow-clone issues before. :-)